# Is it possible to detect if a user has opened a new tab?

Tags: javascript, browser

We are developing a quiz platform where we want to detect if the user opens a new tab during the quiz. The user is not allowed to open a new tab and we want to track this to notify the teacher managing the quiz. We are targeting the major browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari).

Is this possible? Thank you

Comment: No, it is not possible. For something like this, you could offer an "anti-cheating extension" for a specific browser, which would have the permissions to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onblur` event of the `window` object and write something like this:

```
function userCheated() {
    // The user cheated by leaving this window (e.g opening another window)
    // Do something
    alert("You can't cheat!");
}

window.onblur = userCheated;
```

**NOTE:** since that when the user goes away from your window you have no more control on the window, the `userCheated` function, due to slow execution, may be executed when the user comes back in your window, so sometimes the alert can show up when the user comes back. I think that it works fine too.

**Browser support:** since that some browsers may not be able to do this, I recommend you to use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) plugin to make things work on more browsers, since that the jQuery API has a lot of compatibility adjustments.

With jQuery the code will be:

```
$(window).onblur(userCheated);
```

Comment: Interesting.  This seems to work in Chrome 36.  Didn't know `window` had an `onblur` event.  http://jsfiddle.net/74Yh5/show/

Comment: If you combine this solution with interval fired for every... Lets say 1 second, you will have very exact results.

Comment: If you use the function inside a Listener, then using setInterval will make no sense because the listener handles exactly when to run the function.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do this using javascript. It would have to be done with an extension for the browser I believe Internet explorer used to have an option for disabling tab browsing, have a look around the extensions for each browser you wish to do this on or look at making one. Would a better solution not be to restrict the websites you don't want them viewing rather than disabling the tab button?

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function userCheated() {
    // The user cheated by leaving this window (e.g opening another window)
    // Do something
    alert("New Tab Opened");
}

window.onblur = userCheated;

</script>`enter code here`
</head>`enter code here`
<body>
window.onblur = userCheated;
</body>
</html>
```